# Background color is not changing when I'm using ColorScheme.fromSeed in Flutter

Tags: flutter, background-color, color-scheme

I was trying to get a darker BG color, like shown below in the code. But it has no effect after using ColorScheme.fromSeed.

```
return MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
     colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(
       seedColor: Colors.white,
       primary: const Color(0xFF0A0E21) ,
       secondary: Colors.purple,
       background: const Color(0xFF0A0E21),
     ),
   ),
   home: InputPage(),
 );
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Checkout this tool to build your color scheme: https://m3.material.io/theme-builder#/custom Background isn't really "the" background.